# Can a proton spontaneously produce a photon?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, interactions

I recently came upon the reaction
$$ p\ +A\rightarrow p\ +\gamma \ +A\rightarrow p\ +p\ +\bar{p}\ +A$$

That is, an energetic proton interacts with a nucleus, produces a photon (while the nucleus remains unchanged), and the photon then produces a pair of proton and antiproton. Given that the energy of the original proton is enough, this should be able to happen.

Is the nucleus $A$ necessary for the interaction? Wouldn't it be able to (spontaneously) happen in its absence as well, if the proton had kinetic energy at least equal to $2m_p$?

Comment: Answered below, my bad. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/527481/how-are-proton-antiproton-pairs-produced

Comment: In that case, consider deleting the question.